# How can I format objects wrapped inside curly braces?

Tags: formatting

It's pretty common for me to have code like this in Python and Javascript.

```
my_obj = [
    { id: 0, name: 'foo', age: 123 },
    { id: 1, name: 'foo', age: 321 }
]
```

What I'd like to automate is formatting it so the results look like this.

```
my_obj = [
    { 
        id: 0, 
        name: 'foo',
        age: 123 
    },
    {
        id: 1, 
        name: 'foo', 
        age: 321 
    }
]
```

Is there a plugin or something that handles this? I could only find vim-align, but it doesn't appear to handle this scenario.

Comment: Replace { with `{\n`, do the same with `[`,`]`,`}` as well. Then, move to first open bracket and press v%= to align everything

Comment: `npm install -g  js-beautify`, then select your desired lines in linewise mode using `V` key and run `!js-beautify` command on them, or `%!js-beautify` to act on all lines.